# How to access firefox functionality with an add-on for which no api exists

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How does one access parts of firefox with an add-on, if no suitable api exists?

Specifically I would like to read and modify the content of the list of past downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Many parts of Firefox are written in XUL, which can be easily extended to add your own scripts and XUL to the page, which is a bit like inserting JS files and HTML into a web page, but for privileged content (addons and Firefox itself). For example, [this manifest](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/blob/master/chrome.manifest) describes some additions I made to non-api'd code of Firefox to tweak some developer tools.